# How to minimize size of file sent to AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-apps-script, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, http-status-code-413

**CURRENTLY**

I have a 3MB image file that I would like to send to AWS Lambda (via API gateway) from Google Apps Script so the file can be processed.

My Lambda API Gateway Request:

```js
  let bytes = file.getBlob().getBytes();
  console.log("Byte Size:"+bytes.length)

  let payload = {
      bytes: bytes,
      type: "image",
  };

  var options = {
    method: "PUT",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
  };

  console.log("Stringified size:"+JSON.stringify(options))

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    API,
    options
  );
```

**ISSUE**

The response I get is:

```
Byte Size:3308814
Stringified size: 11886033

Exception: Request failed for API returned code 413.
Truncated server response: HTTP content length exceeded 10485760 bytes.
```

**QUESTION**

What am I doing wrong such that the total package balloons from 3.3MB to over 10.4MB in my payload?

Comment: Although from your question, unfortunately, I'm not sure about the URL and the specification of the API you want to use, for example, I think that in your `options`, it is required to modify. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params) When you modify it to `var options = {method: "PUT", contentType: "application/json", payload: JSON.stringify(payload)};`, what result will you obtain? If this was not the direct solution to your issue, can you provide the official document of the specification of API you want to use?

Comment: What's the size of `JSON.stringify(payload)`?

Comment: @Dunedan, that was a good question that I also looked into. 11.8MB for the payload. So, it seems this is more of a Javascript JSON.stringify issue, rather than anything to do with the API. Maybe I will see if there is a way I can send the data without stringifying it.

Comment: Did you try send it as binary data, or string after `base64`?

Comment: Can you try gzipping: `Content-Type: application/javascript;
Content-Encoding: gzip;`,https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#gzipblob

Comment: @marcin, all my code is above. How do if I sent it as binary or string after `base64`?

Comment: I *think* I have made some progress. Following example from https://stackoverflow.com/q/38809183/1730260 I was able to send the image file using contentType `multipart/form-data` to my Lambda. But now the body of the request is in an unusual format that I am working out how to use :)